# Logitec MX Master S2 Bluetooth smoother than unifying receiver

Tags: windows-10, mouse, logitech-mouse, mouse-cursor

Windows 10 machine.
Install Logitec software and setup without any issue.
But I constantly have the bad experience with pointer movement.
I cannot move the pointer precisely to any specific spot.
But using some basic wired mouse I can have precise movement without any issue.

Later on I found out when I pair this mouse(MX Master S2) using Logitech Unifying Receiver, then pointer movement became sticky.
But if I paired with Bluetooth, looked like it is much better movement.
Anyone knows what was the issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Later on I found out when I pair this mouse(MX Master S2) using Logitech Unifying Receiver, then pointer movement became sticky. But if I paired with Bluetooth, looked like it is much better movement. Anyone knows what was the issue?

Logitech Unifying Receiver uses 2.4 GHz which means any numbers of devices could contribute to interference while the BT functionality is much more resilient to interference.  I suggest using BT over 2.4 GHz.

Comment: Just as an example turn the microwave on and try to mouse around with the Unifying receiver: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_oven#Principles       "Consumer ovens usually use 2.45 gigahertz (GHz)[...] while large industrial/commercial ovens often use 915 megahertz (MHz)"